# Installing anaconda to different folder from home on Linux

Tags: linux, anaconda

I want to install Anaconda to a different path such as /opt on my linux server, but I keep getting ERROR: File or directory already exists: /opt, even though there's no files or directory in there. It won't let me install unless I install it in the home folder, any ideas why and how to resolve this problem?

Comment: I had the same problem, I think I was pushing the space bar at the end, or the folder really was already there and I had to delete it.

Answer (score 10):

You need to give also the name of the folder that it will create, like:

```
/opt/anaconda3
```

anaconda3 folder doesn't exist yet, but the installer will create it.

Answer (score 10):

At the time of installation of the anaconda it will ask for the path where anaconda to be installed as follows:

```
Do you accept the license terms? [yes|no]
Please answer 'yes' or 'no':'
>>> yes
Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/root/anaconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below
```

Here we press enter if you want to install it in root/. But if you want to install anaconda into another dir. you can specify the path and anconda3 as the dir name in it as follows:

```
[/root/anaconda3] >>>  /opt/anaconda3
```

press Enter. You will see the following as the output in the terminal:

```
PREFIX= /opt/anaconda3
installing: python-3.6.3-hc9025b9_1 ...
```

It means it started installing the anaconda on the specified path/dir i.e. in /opt/anaconda3. complete the installation.

Answer (score 3):

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh      
Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /opt/miniconda3
```